# Clearing "Generate in DDL" Option

Tags: oracle-sql-data-modeler

I have used a transformation to create a template table in my relational model.  I can programmatically clear the option so that the table doesn't get engineered to the logical model (it contains the "standard" who & when auditing columns), but I can't seem to clear the option that would prevent its DDL from being generated.

I tried setShouldGenerateScript( false ) with no luck.  Looking at the table's properties in the diagram shows that Engineering box is cleared, but the Generate DDL box is not.

Does anyone know which setter method should be called?

Answer (score 0):

Found out the appropriate method to use.  My statement should have been:

nTable.setMarkedGenerate( false );

This worked just fine.  Unfortunately, it is not in the XML class documentation that I have -- no wonder I couldn't find it.